# Variable sumatoria en bucle dentro de una condición PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando un bucle while y dentro de ese bucle necesito hacer una condicion para que me muestre si lo que tengo dentro de un array ya se encuentra o no. El caso es que quiero que cuando haga la condicion me vaya auto sumando las cantidades del producto, este es el codigo:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $stock_actual=$row['stock'];
    $codigo=$row['codigo'];
    $cantidad= $row['cantidad'];
    if (in_array($codigo, $array)) {
        $_SESSION['conteo'] = (($_SESSION['conteo']) - ($cantidad));
    } else {
        $_SESSION['conteo'] = ($stock_actual - $cantidad);
    }
    $array[] = $codigo;
```

El problema que tengo es que la variable de sesion 'conteo', no guarda el valor como deberia, adjunto foto para que quede mas claro.
Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cual es el campo donde se encuentra el valor de "Codigo2"? ¿Podrías agregar el código que usas para armar la tabla?

Comment: ¿Cuáĺ es la finalidad de la variable de sesión aquí si al final terminas metiendo el valor de `$codigo` en `$array`  ¿? Intento encontrarle la lógica a tu programa y no la encuentro.